# encodeURIComponent error in IE11

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-11

The error I'm getting is not all that helpful:

> SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

And the code throwing it is

```
  $('#my-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'http://www.example.com/'+encodeURIComponent(data.name);
    link.target = '_blank';
    if(document.createEvent){
      // for IE 11
      eventMouse = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
      eventMouse.initMouseEvent("click",true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);
    } else {
      eventMouse = new MouseEvent('click');
    }
    link.dispatchEvent(eventMouse);
  });
```

where `data.name` is what I'm getting back from an AJAX return to create this button's click handler function and is a location string like "Nashville, TN". The code works fine on Chrome & Firefox but breaks in IE 11. If I remove `+encodeURIComponent(data.name)` it works fine in IE 11 as well, but that's sort of the important part. Microsoft's [encodeURIComponent documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeh9cef7(v=vs.94).aspx) also leads me to believe that this function shouldn't be causing any issues in IE 11 either.

Comment: Are you on standard mode or has IE decided to go quirks mode for you? Also, your data is not declared or shown here so we can't really see if you are actually placing a string.

Comment: what's data? Does it have a name? What is it's name?

Comment: Edited to include example string for `data.name`.